# Script tags contained in jQuery AJAX response not evaluated when inserted into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

According to the jQuery documentation for $.ajax, "included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.". When I use ajax to grab the content of a dialog box, which in turn contains a script tag for displaying a ReCaptcha box, the ReCaptcha box does not appear when added to the DOM. According to FireBug, the script tag is also now missing from the added content. Navigation directly to the dialog content displays the ReCaptcha just fine.

Does anyone know why this may be occuring and/or know a work around? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code in action can be viewed here:

https://dustinhendricks.com/

Then click "Register Now".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Google reCAPTCHA AJAX API](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX). Using the CAPTCHA this way should fix your problem.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Does the script try to do things like document.write()? That won't work when loaded dynamically, only on the initial page load.

In general, scripts contained in HTML that is innerHTML'd is not evaluated consistently across browsers. To fix that, jQuery actually looks for script tags and executes them manually.

But that doesn't really matter. Even if jQuery didn't do that, the script would be running in a different type of context than it normally is when a page is loading for the first time. It's not really an 'inline script' anymore, and a lot of 3rd party scripts were written with it being 'inline' as an assumption. You'll have to figure out what the script is doing and find a way to call it with dynamic content.

Comment: Infinitesloop is right. The script you're linking to does "document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" s'+'rc="' + RecaptchaState.server + 'js/recaptcha.js"></scr'+'ipt>');" Use directions from http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX instead